# How do I keep a div within the max-width and always on top

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm not entirely sure how to describe my question on technical terms but I'm not sure how to execute it.  I have a div that I want to position on a page.  It should remain within another div that has a max-width.  So when the browser window is increased, this div in a div will never go outside the max-width of the other div.

However when you decrease the size of the browser window, I don't want this div to be hidden.  I want it to remain on top of everything and just align itself to the edge of the browser window.

Does that make sense?  I have an image:

[image]

The dark rectangle doesn't go outside a certain max-width.  When the browser is smaller, it pushes up against the browser edge and always remains visible.

How do I do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="Parent">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Parent{
  width:200px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
top:200px;
}
.main{
  width:700px;
  margin:auto;
  height:1000px;
  background:blue;

}
```

​
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/qhCsJ/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mk9KV/